# Is there a good way to plot graph from mathml or latex?

Tags: javascript, latex, mathml

I want to plot math function from MathML or Latex.
javascript lib is best choice.

Which i want do is like this: [www.desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/)
input a MathML or Latex string such as  y=x^2 ,then plot it.

Comment: Could you rephrase the *question* better?

Comment: Could you give an example of such a *function*? For simple functions use e.g. the latex package `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 1):

http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/mathml/asciimath.html is a great resource which has been around for a long time.  The sandbox ( http://mathcs.chapman.edu/~jipsen/math/index.php/ASCIIMathML/ASCIIMathMLSandbox.html ) shows how to use graphs.  It was initially designed to display math equations using MathML, but has been extended to calculate graphs, too.